# Octave Boxplot Axis

Tags: octave, boxplot

I would like to create multiple boxplot in one graph by using octave. I try to set the x-axis that associates each data.
Here is my code

```
x = [1, 2, 4];
y1 = [6, 2, 3];
y2 = [1, 7, 3];
y3 = [1, 9, 2];

boxplot ({y1,y2,y3});
set(gca,'XTickLabel',x);
refresh;
```

but the result looks strange. The axis appears three times. 
I want to see x-axis 1 for data y1, 2 for data y2 and 4 for data y3
According to [Octave Documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/statistics/function/boxplot.html), I could not find how we could set the axis. I found Matlab could do that :( 
Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before `set(gca,'XTickLabel',x);` you have to add `set(gca, 'xtick', [1:3]);`. This makes sure that each (and only each) box in the plot is assigned an x-axis number before these numbers are overridden by manual labels.

Here's the full code:

```
x = [1, 2, 4];
y1 = [6, 2, 3];
y2 = [1, 7, 3];
y3 = [1, 9, 2];

boxplot ({y1,y2,y3});
set(gca, 'xtick', [1:3]);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',x);
refresh;
```